# How does socket.setSoTimeout works?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I have this code into a service:

```
  InputStream readeIn = socket.getInputStream();
    char [] buffer = new char[1024];

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(readeIn));

    while((counter = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
     socket.setSoTimeout(300000);
     //read here
    }
```

I would ask you 2 questions:

- if, after 300000 milliseconds, it doesn't read anything, there is an exception?
- every time the while loop comes up, it refreshes the socket timeout? for example I read something but time out is at 100 seconds, when it comes up return at 300 seconds?

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: You only set the timeout once when creating the socket, no need to refresh anything.

Comment: @ci_ I need to keep up a tcp connection and I want to check if connection is lost

Comment: And? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @ci_ everytime I read something I want to refresh the counter of the socket

Comment: You should get an exception if nothing happens when the timeout duration has passed, but only if you set the timeout _before_  the blocking operation.

Comment: If you read something that timer is automatically reset according the documentation. This is for closing the socket if there was nothing to read in that specified interval. Checking if a connection is lost is something different. But why opening a new thread? You should have stayed at the other.

Comment: There is no need to refresh anything, if you read something, there is no timeout, if you try to read again, the same timeout applies.

Comment: I want to do this: wait 5 minutes with the timeout; if socket doesn't read anything, close it but if it read something, refresh the counter with other 5 minutes

Comment: You have to put that statement before you do a read. This was said in the first comment by ci_ already. Set it once and that should be all.

Comment: Ok but if I read something, socket is closing after five minutes?

Comment: Yes. According the documentation. But set it at 10 seconds to test and see.

Comment: And if i want to continue to read, after this 5 minutes? I want close the connection if there is nothing to read

Comment: Now first tell if using this method works.

Comment: Ok..it works but every 5 minutes connection break down..then?